# Which version of JQuery Mobile is to be used to get fixed header and footer

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have been using `jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css` file. But this version is not supporting fixed header and footer. I need to change to later versions like JQuery Mobile 1.1.2.

When I downloaded it has many CSS files. Which file needs to be included in the code to serve the purpose?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the the [1.3.2 JQM version](http://jquerymobile.com/download/), in this version the fixed header and footer are supported.

You can use the `jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css` or the `jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css.min` version.